# Regular Expression (Regex) in C#

Tags: c#, regex

how i can Replace those string in C#

```
I need //cursive// text and //cursive// text.
```

INTO:

```
I need <i>cursive</i> text and <i>cursive</i> text.
```

AND

```
This si me [website[http://www.website.com]] and other me [website[http://www.website2.com]].
```

INTO:

```
This si me <a href='http://www.website.com'>website</a> and other me <a href='http://www.website2.com'>website</a>.
```

Solutiuon for first act:

```
string Test = "Mama ma //hodne// prace protoze //neni// doma.";
string Result = Regex.Replace(Test, "//(.+?)//", "<i>$1</i>");
```

Solution for second act:

```
string Test2 = "Mama ma [hodne[http://www.someurl.com]]  protoze [neni[http://www.someurl.com]] doma.";
string Result2 = Regex.Replace(Test2, "\\[(.+?)\\[(.+?)\\]\\]", "<a href='$2' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use a markdown library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888985/what-markdown-c-library-should-i-use ?

Comment: The correct answer is, don't use a regex. Use a parser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @stusmith: The OP wants to convert from plain text to HTML, so a regex is probably good enough. A parser would probably do the job too, just not a HTML parser.

Comment: Markdown does this sort of stuff with regex's (lots of them!)

Comment: @lukeh exactly, I want only simple regex for those two acts.

Comment: If the user wants to display this text in cursive, how would the slashes be escaped? "cur//sive"

Comment: @Lazarus: Nothing inherently right with it either.

Comment: Jin - You are hereby encouraged to add your solution as an answer and accept it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it

Answer (score 0):

***Solution found by JinDave:***

Solutiuon for first act:

```
string Test = "Mama ma //hodne// prace protoze //neni// doma.";
string Result = Regex.Replace(Test, "//(.+?)//", "<i>$1</i>");
```

Solution for second act:

```
string Test2 = "Mama ma [hodne[http://www.someurl.com]]  protoze [neni[http://www.someurl.com]] doma.";
string Result2 = Regex.Replace(Test2, "\\[(.+?)\\[(.+?)\\]\\]", "<a href='$2' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
```

Comment: You just copied the solution from the question and pasted it here. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Well, that's... not quite the way to go, in my opinion... I've encouraged the OP to add an answer.